# Calendar.getDisplayName returning null

Tags: android

I am trying to get display name of a month through this:

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String monthName=c.getDisplayName(monthOfYear, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US);//monthOfYear: 6
```

but the function is always returning `null`

please help me.

Comment: What is the value of `monthOfYear`? If it not `Calendar.MONTH`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: value is`6` and expecting it to return july. Else how can i get the display name of one particular month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider ditching `Calendar`, it's a little heavy weight for such a simple task:

```
int monthOfYear = Calendar.JULY; // 6
String monthName = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US).getShortMonths()[monthOfYear];
```

Note that you can cache (even in a `static` variable) return value of `getShortMonths()` and index for different months later, just be careful, numbering starts from 0 (=JANUARY). It's worth caching since `getShortMonths()` returns a new mint array every time.

Please consider using `DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US)` instead of `new` if you're targeting > API Level 9.

Answer (score 1):

> Else how can i get the display name of one particular month.

Step #1: Create a `Calendar` for a date that is in that particular month.

Step #2: Call `getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US)` on the `Calendar` object from Step #1.

Step #3: Beer.

Note: step #3 is optional.